Incompatible types even though my class extends ARFragments
I am trying to put a custom fragment into my activity_layout, but I get the following error:
error: incompatible types: CustomARFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, arFragment);

I don't quite get my head around why this occurs, as I am still really new to Android Studio and everything.
My Class should extend ARFragment as needed
I first tried to use a fragment in my xml but got the same error.
after that i tried to replace the contentframe with my fragment:
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, arFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


My CustomARFragmentclass looks like this:
import com.google.ar.core.Config;
import com.google.ar.core.Session;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;

public class CustomARFragment extends ArFragment {

  @Override
  protected Config getSessionConfiguration(Session session) {
    Config config = new Config(session);
    config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
    config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
    session.configure(config);

    this.getArSceneView().setupSession(session);
    return config;
  }
}

I am unsure if its an dependeny Problem as I had to exclude something because of an duplicated class error from sceneform.ux
dependencies {
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    annotationProcessor("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")

    implementation("com.google.ar:core:1.44.0")
    implementation ("com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1")
    implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.8.2")

    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.65.1")
    implementation ("com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.24.0")
    implementation ("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-vision:3.45.0")
    implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.9.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
}
configurations {
    all {
        exclude(group= "com.android.support", module= "support-compat")
    }

(I know that are many imports, I kind of collected them while programming the other classes and by now I am not even 100% sure which ones I need)
Could somebody help me understand what's happening with my arfragment here?
When I try to not put my arfragment somewhere but just try to initialisie ist, I get the following runtime error (if that helps solving it)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap; at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.<clinit>(Fragment.java:81)

When I open the Fragment class I get the message Library source does not match the bytecode for class Fragment
I just followed instructions for that part so far and cant wrap my head around what's wrong. Maybe someone could help me here?
